Ways to isolate cpus between different processes
I'm running speed tests between different versions of the same application. I want to be able to allocate a fixed set of cpus to each application. For example I want to run the application on exactly two cpus and not more. Also I want these two cpus to be exclusive to this process so that no other processes can "steal" cputime and reduce the score of the test.
Is there a way to do this on Linux? I have heard about cgroups, containers and docker. Will those be of any help? Also, which approach is the simplest (not necessarily the most user friendly), and which gives me the most control?
Also I'm a bit worried about hyper-threading. If I allocate a single logical cpu to this test process, and another process is hyper-threaded during the test, will this not make the test result worse? I would then also need to separate cpus by physical cpus.

ah, sorry,  linked you to the wrong existing question. you'll want to read How to dedicate a CPU to a process

regarding hyper-threading: that's why you typically only assign consecutive pairs of CPU cores with taskset, isolcpus.

@MarcusMüller That sounds interesting. However, is there a way to do this without rebooting every single time I want to run a test?

taskset and giving your process under test a low niceness will in most cases do the trick, but would not make guarantees

@MarcusMüller So if I want this guarantee I will have to reboot? Also, niceness does not protect against hyper-threading right? If the process only uses a single logical cpu with a low niceness, another process is still completely free to run hyper-threaded on the second logical cpu, or am I mistaken?

yes, but it's typically unlikely to be scheduled there if system load is low.

Thank you for the help!

Does this answer your question? How to dedicate a CPU to a process

If having hypethreading enabled or not is impeding your tests, it can be toggled on a running system, assuming that the system is booted with hyperthreading enabled. Disable the "virtual" cores by setting /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{sib}/online to zero.

I managed to solve the problem and this was indeed part of the solution. Using cgroups for the rest worked well.

@spinosarus123 would you care to write up how you solved the problem as a proper answer?

@StephenKitt Ok, I posted the link to the source code. Can you read c?

@spinosarus123 thanks, I have indeed been known to read C ;-).

@StephenKitt Haha, I did not check your profile!

I managed to solve it using cgroups. See https://github.com/Spinojara/testbit/blob/master/src/cgroup.c.
